# Getting notified when the current application changes in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I want to be notified when the current application will change. I looked at NSWorkspace. It will send notifications only when your own application becomes active or loses the activity.
I want to be informed about every application. How can I do this in Cocoa?

Comment: It is impossible to get this information from Cocoa. You have to use the Carbon Event Manager to get notifications on when a process other than your own becomes active.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank you Jason.
kEventAppFrontSwitched in Carbon Event Manager is the magic word

```
- (void) setupAppFrontSwitchedHandler
{
    EventTypeSpec spec = { kEventClassApplication,  kEventAppFrontSwitched };
    OSStatus err = InstallApplicationEventHandler(NewEventHandlerUPP(AppFrontSwitchedHandler), 1, &spec, (void*)self, NULL);

    if (err)
        NSLog(@"Could not install event handler");
}

- (void) appFrontSwitched {
    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activeApplication]);
}
```

And the handler

```
static OSStatus AppFrontSwitchedHandler(EventHandlerCallRef inHandlerCallRef, EventRef inEvent, void *inUserData)
{
    [(id)inUserData appFrontSwitched];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I made a little example for somebody that actually posted notifications a while back, but I couldn't find it. You gave a nice summary, you should accept this answer :)

Comment: Remark: To successfully build an application using this, you have to add the Carbon and Core Services Frameworks to your build and include <Carbon/Carbon.h> and <CoreServices/CoreServices.h> in the implementation file that contains the handler.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801976/mixing-c-functions-in-an-objective-c-class/ on how to mix C with Objective-C

Answer (score 26):

If you're targeting 10.6 or later there's a notification for this:

```
// NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(foremostAppActivated:) name:NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification object:nil];
```

Apple docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-SW97

Comment: Confirmed working in 2014 on OS X 10.9 (except I had to remove the colon in the @selector method). Thank you!

Comment: The colon is there because I expect your selector to look like this:
`- (void)foremostAppActivated:(NSNotification *)notification`