# Can Objective-C code call C code and vice-verse? (mix and match them)

Tags: objective-c, c

For example, can Objective-C call a C function, which calls Objective-C?

```
(UIColor *) getUIColorWithRGB(int r, int g, int b) {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed: r / 255.0 green: g / 255.0 blue: b / 255.0 alpha: 1];
}

@implementation UIColorCollection

+(UIColor *) lightCyanColor {
    return getUIColorWithRGB(224, 255, 255);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801976/mixing-c-functions-in-an-objective-c-class

Comment: Yes.  Call the C code as you normally would code a C call.  To call back to Objective-C the C code must be in a .m or .mm file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If talking about possibility, it is possible. Just remove the brackets in the return value of the C function:

```
UIColor * getUIColorWithRGB(int r, int g, int b) {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed: r / 255.0 green: g / 255.0 blue: b / 255.0 alpha: 1];
}
```

Not sure whether this is OK as a programming practice, though.

Comment: ha, the different syntax is driving me nuts... I think if it is RGB, then 3 numbers is much more readable than `withRed: Green: Blue:` syntax

Comment: @動靜能量: I think you can use `#define` to create a macro for this.

Comment: oh i see... that's true... I am just not used to macros since I haven't used it for about 16 years... since 1996 when I switched over to Perl