# iOS: Convertion between xml and wbxml

Tags: ios

I am trying to convert xml data in wbxml and the reverse too via my program. When I was searching in google, I found the following link was querying the same.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088507/i-there-any-library-xml2wbxml-wbxml-for-iphone.

But, as per the answer, it doesn't have any sample source which converts between xml and wbxml data.

Can someone please guide me to get some referral code which converts between xml and wbxml data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

- http://wbxmllib.sourceforge.net/html/files.html
- http://wbxmllib.sourceforge.net/html/wbxml2xml__tool_8c-source.html
- http://wbxmllib.sourceforge.net/html/xml2wbxml__tool_8c-source.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @4e6: the OP is asking for some code: if you follow that link you'll find C code you can probably use with iOS.

Comment: The problem with link only answers is that a link kan become a dead link and then the answer is useless. So it is advisiable to give at least some summary of the post.

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe: I agree with you, but in this case we're not talking about few lines of code you can copy, paste and try

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for the reply. But, don't we have any third party lib written in Obj C to achieve what i want, so i can use directly! From these four links, i don't know what to do further.

Comment: @user1729070: as far as I know, there's no Objective-C library. But: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801976/mixing-c-functions-in-an-objective-c-class

Comment: Ok. Could you tell me atleast this would be possible by an Obj C expert to convert C to Obj C especially for my requirement and does anyone already achieved it?

Comment: @user1729070: Objective-C IS C (Objective-C is built upon the C language and from Objective-C you can call C functions). An Objective-C expert could do what you are asking for.