# C function and variable inside Objective-C class implementation?

Tags: objective-c, c, compiler-construction

I can define c function and variable inside Objective-C class implementation like this:

```
@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    cfunction();
}

// variable inside class
NSString *message = @"this is c function inside objective-c class";

// c function inside class
void cfunction() {
    NSLog(@"%@", message);
}

@end
```

**RESULT**

```
this is c function inside objective-c class
```

This code works without any warnings and errors.
Is it valid Objective-C code?
Is it safe to define variable and c function inside Objective-C class?
Are there documentations about this language specifications?

Comment: See the foundation framework - almost all C

Comment: @JustinMeiners thanks! but this question is not "Can I use C in Objective-C?".

Comment: I see - more about in a objective C class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is correct and safe, but you should try to avoid it. If you need to have some C-function, define it in a separate file (and declare it in a separate header file).

Technically, Obj-C is a thin layer on top of the C language and you can use any C feature anywhere in a Obj-C source code. However you should conform to the coding style and not mix the two languages.

Comment: "you should conform to the coding style and not mix the two languages." - *which* coding style? How *not to mix* the "two" languages? Is it bad style if I write `- (int)foo { return 1 + 2; }`, just because `1 + 2` is a C expression itself?

Comment: I meant not to mix e.g. C-structs and Obj-C objects. Not to mix C-functions and Obj-C methods.

Comment: @kuba thanks! In normal C, `cfunction()` must define before `-viewDidLoad`.
But if I define `cfunction()` between @implementation and @end, `cfunction()` can be defined after `-viewDidLoad`.
And as H2CO3 said, `functions can directly access private and protected ivars of an object`.
I think defining c-function inside @implementation is more than c language. But I can't find documentation.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it valid Objective-C code?

Yes, it is.

> Is it safe to define variable and c function inside Objective-C class?

Yes, it is. One particular property of functions defined within classes is that such functions can directly access private and protected ivars of an object which is instance of the specified class.

> Are there documentation about this language specification?

See the discussion around [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801976/mixing-c-functions-in-an-objective-c-class)

Comment: thanks. but i couldn't find the documentation in [the SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801976/mixing-c-functions-in-an-objective-c-class) . If there is no documentation, is it dangerous to rely on that feature?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, previous answer is very wrong in its third part.

C functions implemented within the @implementation of an objective-C class are NOT methods of that class, but rather simple, global C functions.

Of course it is OK to write them there, and sometimes even beneficial because they're "private to the class" -- other code will not see them, as they are scoped within the @implementation.

However - they **can not access any iVars, or self, or super**, or anything related to the class or instance. They are C functions and not Obj-C methods.

Any attempt to access iVars or self or super etc. will produce a compiler error saying "symbol xxx is unknown".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the other answers (especially Motti's):

You can prefix the C-function by the 'static' keyword.
'static' means that it will only be possible to use that function from within the C file it's present in. It will not be possible to export it or call it from outside that C-file.
Eg. If you have a static function in a header-file, you will get multiple copies of it.

It's as simple as this:

Prototype:

```
static void cfunction();
```

Implementation:

```
static void cfunction() {
    NSLog(@"%@", message);
}
```

-Now try to call it from code in a different source-file.

...And there's nothing wrong with mixing Objective-C and C.
Generally speaking: Objective-C is **sluggish**. C++ is *slow* and C is quite fast.
-So if you have subroutines (or inline functions) that you call a lot, make those C functions instead of Objective-C, because ObjC will drag your loops down.