# Use of undeclared identifier error in my case

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xctest, xctestcase

My code invokes a C library function:

```
@implementation Store
  ...
  -(void) doWork {
    // this is a C function from a library
    int data = getData(); 
    ...
  }
end
```

I am unit testing the above function, I want to mock the C function `getData()` in my test, here is my test case:

```
@interface StoreTests : XCTestCase {
    int mData;
    Store *store;
}
@end

@implementation StoreTests

-(void) setUp {
  [super setUp];
   mData = 0;
   store = [[Store alloc] init];
}

-(void) testDoWork {
  // this call will use the mocked getData(), no problem here.
  [store doWork];
}

// mocked getData()
int getData() {
   mData = 10; // Use of undeclared identifier 'mData', why?
   return mData;
}

...
@end
```

Why I get complier error:
`Use of undeclared identifier 'mData'` inside mocked `getData()` function?

Comment: `-(int)getData() {`

Comment: No, if I change to `-(int)getData(){`, I get weird compiler error `expect function body`, my current code works just fine, the mocked function is invoked by production code. The problem comes only when I assign value to mData inside mocked function. Again, it is a C function.

Comment: I understand what you meant, and I tried, and then I wrote the above comment.

Comment: But you can't define a c function as an instance method. `mData` is an instance variable so you should access it via `self` when you want to assign a new value to it. Maybe you might want to take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801976/mixing-c-functions-in-an-objective-c-class).

Comment: Thanks, I also tried `self.mData = 10`, same error. Yep, I guess you are right that C function is not considered as a instance function. My main point of posting this question is to find a solution for it so that I can assign value to a instance variable inside the C function. Currently, I found one way is to define it above `@interface StoreTests : XCTestCase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how instance methods and variables work.

Every instance method has a variable `self` which references the current instance (or "current object") and a use of an instance variable, such as `mData`, is shorthand for accessing that variable using `self`, e.g `self->mData`, where `->` is the (Objective-)C operator for field access. So your `setup` method written "long hand" is:

```
-(void) setUp {
   [super setUp];
   self->mData = 0;
   self->store = [[Store alloc] init];
}
```

But where does `self`, the reference to the instance, itself come from? Well it's not magical, just hidden, it is passed to an instance method automatically as a hidden extra argument. *At this point which switch to pseudo-code to show this.* Your `setup` method is *effectively* compiled as:

```
-(void) setUp withSelf:(StoreTest *)self {
   [super setUp];
   self->mData = 0;
   self->store = [[Store alloc] init];
}
```

and a call such as:

```
StoreTests *myStoreTests = ...

[myStoreTests setup];
```

is effectively compiled as something like:

```
[myStoreTests setup withSelf:myStoreTests];
```

automatically adding the extra `self` argument.

Now all the above only applies to *methods*, and enables them to access instance variables and methods, it does not apply to plain C functions - they have no hidden `self` argument and cannot access instance variables.

The solution you mention in the answer you added of declaring `mData` outside of the interface:

```
int mData;
@interface StoreTests : XCTestCase {
   Store *store;
}
@end
```

changes `mData` into a *global variable*, instead of being an *instance variable*. C functions can access global variables. However this does mean that every instance of the class shares the same `mData`, there is only one `mData` in this case rather than one for every instance.

Making an instance variable into a global is therefore not a general solution to to issues like this, however as it is unlikely that you will have more than one instance of your `StoreTests` class it is a suitable solution in this case.

You should however make one change: you can only have one global variable with a given name with a program, so your `mData` must be unique and is accessible by *any* code within your program, not just the code of `StoreTests`. You can mitigate this my declaring the variable as `static`:

```
static int mData;
```

this keeps the variable as global but only makes it visible to code within the same *file* as the declaration, which is probably just the code of `StoreTests`.

HTH

Comment: Very inofrmative. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution for my question, that is declare `mData` above `@interface StoreTests : XCTestCase`, something like this:

```
int mData;
@interface StoreTests : XCTestCase {
    Store *store;
}
@end
...
```