# Getting Highest Level of Bit Shifted Enum Value using Switch Statment

Tags: objective-c

I have a bit shifting enum:

```
typdef enum:{
    TypeA = 1 << 0,
    TypeB = 1 << 1,
    TypeC = 1 << 2,
    TypeD = 1 << 3
} my_type_t
```

And I was trying to determine the highest level it's in of a value, for example, `7` would be equivalent to `TypeC`, using a switch statement. For example:

```
NSString* stringType(NSUInteger value){
    switch (value){
        case (TypeA):{
            return @"TypeA";
        }
        case (TypeA | TypeB):{
            return @"TypeB";
        }
        case (TypeA | TypeB | TypeC):{
            return @"TypeC";
        }
        case (TypeA | TypeB | TypeC | TypeD):{
            return @"TypeD";
        }
        default:
            return @"Unknown"
    }
}
```

but I always got `Unknown` value, any idea why and how to fix this?

Comment: `@"xxx"` is not C, please remove the `c` tag or change the code

Comment: It's a mix of C and ObjC.

Comment: you cannot "mix" languages. It's objC, not C. Please change the tag

Comment: Yes you can, `NSString* stringType(NSUInteger value)` is C mixed with ObjC, the function declaration is C, the returned type is ObjC. If that rule applied, most of questions here are wrongly tagged. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/828943/14298873

Comment: What if `value` is 4?

Comment: This code is not a valid C code. It would not be accepted by compliant C compiler. The link refers to *calling* C functions from from ObjC code what is a completely different topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the type of your typedef (i.e. NSUInteger):

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    TypeA = 1 << 0,
    TypeB = 1 << 1,
    TypeC = 1 << 2,
    TypeD = 1 << 3
} my_type_t;
```

With that in place, `stringType(7)` returns `TypeC` for me.